# How to pass charcode to jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

i want to pass charcode on keyup event to jquery plugin.Actually till now i was working with jquery function and my work was like this.
my html

```
<body>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="working.js"></SCRIPT>
<textarea name="source" id="src1" cols="150" rows="20"  onkeyup="showRelated(event)"></textarea>
</body>
```

my working.js

```
function showRelated(e) {


    var unicode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;       
    var str = $('#src1').val(); 
    var spaceCheck=32;
    var checkEnter=13; 
    if (unicode == spaceCheck || unicode==checkEnter) {  
    {
        //my code goes here
    }
}
```

Now I need to do it using jquery plugin.So my hlml will be

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.requireplugin.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea name="source" id="src1" cols="150" rows="20"></textarea></td>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#src1").keyup(function() {
$('#src1').pluginmethod();
});
</script>
</body>
```

my jquery.requireplugin.js

```
(function($) {

$.fn.pluginmethod = function() {

        this.each(function() {
        var $str = $('#src1'); 
        var som= $str.val();
        //here i need to use charcode 

        });
};

})(jQuery);
```

Now i want to know how can i pass charcode to the plugin so that i can use it inside plugin like i did in workimg.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the immediate solution to your problem is given in the fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/q5fgpbyz/2/

where you can simply pass the charCode and use it in the plugin-

```
$("#src1").keyup(function(e) {
    $('#src1').pluginmethod(e.keyCode);
});
```